# Как наиболее эффективно выполнить операцию деления двух массивов valarray

Tags: c++, массивы, числа, деление

Есть массив комплексных чисел

```
std::valarray<std::complex<double>> Buf;
```

как наиболее эффективно выполнить операцию деления одного участка этого массива на другой?
Например, если нужно разделить участок с 1024 по 2047 элемент на участок с 0 по 1023 элемент.
Что лучше всего использовать вместо циклов типа "for"?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно разделить вторую половину `std::valarray` на первую:

```
#include <valarray>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::valarray<std::complex<double>> buf {
            {1., 0.},
            {2., 0.},
            {3., 0.},
            {4., 0.},
    };

    buf[std::slice{2, 2, 1}] /= buf[std::slice{0, 2, 1}];

    for (const auto& item : buf) {
        std::cout << item << '\n';
    }
}
```

Дока https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice

Comment: я спрашивал, как наиболее эффективно выполнить операцию деления массивов типа valarray. Твой ответ показывает, как можно разделить или как наиболее эффективно можно разделить?

Comment: @Natal04ka показывает, как делить в `std::valarray`. Для максимальной эффективности этот класс вообще не стоит использовать

Comment: а какой класс стоит использовать??

Comment: @Natal04ka векторизированный/распараллеленный цикл for, из того что сам знаю (не эксперт в выжимании максимальных скоростей). Вы уверены, что это bottleneck вашей программы и надо делать оптимизацию относительно моего решения?